# ICommand doesn't update the IsEnabled on a button using CanExecute

Tags: wpf, mvvm, canexecute

I have a very simple button binded to a command

```
    <Button Content="Add" Margin="10,10,10,0" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" ></Button>
```

My command code

```
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    private bool CanExecuteSaveCommand()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0;
    }

    private void CreateSaveCommand()
    {
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => this.SaveExecute(), param => CanExecuteSaveCommand());
    }

    public void SaveExecute()
    {
        PharmacyItem newItem = new PharmacyItem();
        newItem.Name = ItemToAdd.Name;
        newItem.IsleNumber = ItemToAdd.IsleNumber;
        newItem.ExpDate = ItemToAdd.ExpDate;
        PI.Add(newItem);
    }
```

The code effectively blocks the command from running based on CanExecuteSaveCommand but the button is never disabled, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show your implementation DelegateCommand? Or are you using an MVVM Framework?

Comment: public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute,
                       Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ICommand.CanExecute()` is called automatically by WPF whenever it thinks the command availability may have changed. This generally tends to be on user activity, eg keyboard events, focus events etc.

Since your command availability changes purely based on time, WPF has no way of guessing that it has changed. Instead you need to give it a hint by calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();`

Since your command availability changes every second, you would need to set up a timer to call this function at least every second.

Note that although `InvalidateRequerySuggested()` is the easiest solution, it will cause WPF to re-evaluate ALL command availabilities. If this is a performance problem, you can raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event on your `ICommand` instance instead.

Comment: If doing this on a background thread, you may need to run this using the Dispatcher.